# Many mysqli_connect() vs many mysqli_select_db()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to reduce the number of queries to the database. But I am afraid that the installation of a database connection a resource-intensive process than the selection of the database. What do you think about it?

What is the right way, and why?

**The first way**

```
class db {

    private $link;

    function __construct() {

        $this->link = mysqli_connect('1.1.1.1', 'user', 'pass');
    }

    function query($sql, $db) {

        mysqli_select_db($this->link, $db);

        return mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
    }
}

$db = new db();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`', 'databaseA');
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`', 'databaseB');
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`', 'databaseC');
}

//connections - 1
//queries - 2 x 3 x 100 = 600
```

**The second way**

```
class db {

    private $links;

    function query($sql, $db) {

        if ( ! isset($this->links[$db]))
            $this->links[$db] = mysqli_connect('1.1.1.1', 'user', 'pass', $db);

        return mysqli_query($this->links[$db], $sql);
    }
}

$db = new db();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`', 'databaseA');
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`', 'databaseB');
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`', 'databaseC');
}

//connections - 3
//queries - 1 x 3 x 100 = 300
```

Comment: i really believe this does not play a role here. it depends more on how much data is inside your tables. setting up 3 different db handles to the same db server is in general no _resource-intensive process_ at all, if yes, i would worry about your whole server setup.

Comment: Your second approach is misleading at least but - correct me if I'm wrong - seems to show what your intentions are: eliminate the one, simple, easy to implement function/method call to select the database before sending queries. Don't burden your query method with that. Make a it a parameter in the constructor or a spearate method with a fluid interface (ie. it returns its own instance so you can do something like $conn->selectdb(...)->prepare(...)) or something else but don't litter the query method ;-)

Comment: VolkerK, in the second approach I establish a connection to the database if it is not previously installed. Your way conn->selectdb->prepare to send 2 requests as the first method.